# Reason behind Robert McCall's fake death

Tags: plot-explanation, the-equalizer

In [The Equalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Equalizer_%28film%29), when McCall visits Plummer's house, Brian Plummer says;

> -You had a nice funeral,
>   in case you were wondering.

Why McCall's death was faked? Even Susan didn't know it, What was McCall's past? Why he lived so quietly? And if he had such incredible skills, intelligence and knowledge then why didn't he use it for a bigger cause? (I know he made promise with his dying wife, but still he made exceptions) Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie did not explain what he was in the past, but based on his skill, we can easily assume a spy of some type.

His death was explained when he was talking with his friend (right before the lady returned in the helicopter).

His death was faked so he could escape that life and basically retire. If you recall the scene where the russian bad guy is investigating Robert's background, he complains that it's clean, too clean.

In summary, his death was faked (either by him or his agency) so that he could retire in peace or to escape his agency.